# Mystery where a woman was taken in a wet sheet and left to freeze, demonstrated with a wet napkin and clothespin

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I'm hoping to rediscover a mystery story I read when I was very young.

The body of a woman had been discovered miles from a remote lodge with no obvious means of death.  A detective suggested that she had been trapped in a wet sheet and left in the cold to freeze.  The entire icy deathtrap was then pushed from a slope and drifted downhill ultimately coming to rest miles from any habitation.  He demonstrated the whole scenario using a wet napkin and a clothespin.  It wasn't a full novel, but a short story, perhaps reminiscent of a Poirot mystery.
This would be in the late 70s or early/mid 80s. It may also have been in a story collection that included "Thus, I refute Beelzy" by Collier.

Answer (score 4):

The story is "The Glass Bridge" by Robert Arthur!  Finally found it!

Comment: Hi @Bobb, that's great. Can you edit your answer to add details such as the collection or the magazine, to help others find it that might be looking in the future?

Comment: You also seem to have accidentally created two different accounts; you may want to look into [merging your accounts](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), which will also allow you to accept your answer.